# Using C# DateTime in IronPython

Tags: c#, ironpython

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't use DateTime in IronPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472553/cant-use-datetime-in-ironpython)

Hi,

I'm having difficulty getting DateTime to work in IronPython with the following code:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("System")
from System import DateTime
```

I get an error saying: Cannot import DateTime.

Anybody know why?

Thanks.